# mpAndroidChart : How to show the value on the last point of the LineChart?

Tags: android, point, linechart, mpandroidchart

The value on the last point of the LineChart doesn't show even 
in the [mpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) example.
always value of the last point can't be seen I tried adding padding , `layout_margin` and  `setExtraOffsets` ..

- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtUiY.png)

I'm using v3.0.0, and this is the LineChart Code:

```
    lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.animateY(2000);
    lineChart.setDrawBorders(false);
    lineChart.setVisibleXRange(3,7);
    YAxis leftAxis=lineChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);

    YAxis rightAxis = lineChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

    IAxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(lineChart);
    XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    xAxis.setTextSize(13);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code you used to generate that chart? Which version of MPAndroidChart are you using?

Comment: I added the code , you can  also check out the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) example it doesn't show there either.

Comment: can you try 
`lineChart.setDragOffsetX(30);`? Does that fix it?

Comment: No that didn't work. it added some padding but the value still not appearing.

Comment: I'll try something else tomorrow and get back to you. But for now, the examples in the MPAndroidChart app are showing the last label correctly. Can you edit your post to include the code for the `DayAxisValueFormatter`? I wonder if there is a problem there.

Comment: `DayAxisValueFormatter` is for the Xaxis and that is working just fine.
what I'm talking about is the values  in the top of each `dataSet` like in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtUiY.png). It doesn't work in my app or the examples in the MPAndroidChart app, and this is [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/UQBMDyN.png) taken from my galaxy S4 and this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/8OHN5Zs.png) taken from Nexus 5 emulator.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue with MPAndroidChart v3.0.1. What happens if you upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work by a **workaround**. 
Add an extra `Entry` for each dataSet after the last `Entry` and then set the `setAxisMaximum` for the xAxis to the last value, like this

```
dataset1.addEntry(new Entry(endDay+1,yValues1[i]));
dataSet2.addEntry(new Entry(endDay+1,yValues2[i]));
dataSet3.addEntry(new Entry(endDay+1,yValues3[i]));
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(endDay+0.1f);`
```